# Oracle: update column with values from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I added a new column to an existing table. I want to populate it with a value which I retrieve from another table.

Table: `EXPORT`

```
Name | email | employeeid | userid
```

Table: `USER`

```
id |  name  | email  | idnumber
```

The new column is `EXPORT.userid`, which I want to equal out to `USER.id`. Please note that `id` and `idnumber` **are NOT the same** - `idnumber` stores the `employeeid` while `id` is a auto-increment PK. `USER.idnumber` is equal to `EXPORT.employeeid`.

I want to populate `EXPORT.userid` with `USER.id` when `export.employeeid = user.idnumber`.

How can I do that with Oracle-compatible SQL-code?

I tried the following, but it throws me an error.

```
UPDATE EXPORT  
   SET userid = ( SELECT id 
                FROM USER 
               WHERE USER.idnumber = EXPORT.employeeid 
                 and USER.EMAIL = EXPORT.email) 
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
             FROM USER
            WHERE USER.idnumber = EXPORT.employeeid 
              and USER.EMAIL = EXPORT.email)
```

But I get this error

```
[Error] Execution (2: 19): ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

Comment: You might try and search that error e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=single-row+subquery+returns+more+than+one+row

Comment: @icefresh:Are you sure that idnumber is the primary key of the user table ,please check it once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, this subquery returns more than one row for given email and idnumber:

```
SELECT id 
                FROM USER 
               WHERE USER.idnumber = EXPORT.employeeid 
                 and USER.EMAIL = EXPORT.email
```

Try using DISTINCT to exclude duplicates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id 
                FROM USER 
               WHERE USER.idnumber = EXPORT.employeeid 
                 and USER.EMAIL = EXPORT.email
```

Or add some sample data to your question. What is the unique key of tables USER and EXPORT?

Comment: :returning multiple records is understandable ,but the question is different ,he defined idnumber as primary key of user table ,and logically that should not return multiple record

Comment: @GauravSoni idnumber is not a primary key of user, it just stores the id of user **idnumber stores the employeeid** However, if id is PK than DISTINCT won't help. So the main question - what is the unique key of USER, it seems that (idnumber, email) is not UK.

Comment: The primary key of user is id, not idnumber.

Comment: select idnumber,email,count(*) cnt from users group by idnumber,email having count(*)>1 .How many you get ?

Comment: It returned three rows. Two empty ones which just included a space. One with an actual value, which I excluded from the update statement. At the end, this one worked fine:

Comment: `UPDATE export
   SET export.USERID = ( SELECT id 
                FROM user 
               WHERE user.idnumber = export.employeeid 
                 and user.EMAIL = export.email
                 and user.idnumber NOT LIKE ' '
                 and user.idnumber NOT IN('123456')) 
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
             FROM user
            WHERE user.idnumber = export.employeeid 
              and user.EMAIL = export.email
              and user.idnumber NOT LIKE ' '
              and user.idnumber NOT IN('123456')
              )`

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following query

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT USER.idnumber, USER.EMAIL, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM USER
    GROUP BY USER.idnumber, USER.EMAIL
) c
WHERE c.cnt > 1
```

If you see any rows, then this is your problem.

For example, if you have a USER table that looks like

```
id |  name    |      email         | idnumber
1  | icefresh | icefresh@what.ever | 100
2  | icefresh | icefresh@what.ever | 100
```

Then your query

```
SELECT id 
FROM USER 
WHERE USER.idnumber = EXPORT.employeeid 
    and USER.EMAIL = EXPORT.email
```

Will return 1 and 2. In order for it to work, it can only return 1 value.